# Ansible "gather_facts: yes" leads to error "module (setup) is missing interpreter line"

Tags: ansible

all,

A very simple playbook,

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: yes
  vars:

  tasks:
    #- setup:
    - debug: msg = "Hostname is {{ ansible_hostname }}"
```

when I set "gather_facts" to "yes", then ansible-playbook reports the below error:

> fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "module (setup) is missing
>   interpreter line"}

I know it's related to the "setup" module, but don't have a clue to dig it. Did anyone meet the similar issue before? Or any suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: Btw, I upgraded Ansible to latest 2.4.3. And "gather_facts: yes" works fine on another server with the same version of Ansible.

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/issues/2762#issuecomment-169392977

Answer (score 1):

This is a reported bug for ansible. The issue can be seen [here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/20702). Although there is a pull request merged in the mainline code for this (see [here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/20717)), if the issue is not fixed for you, would be good to re-open it. Also, try the fixed provided in the `Common issues` section [here](https://github.com/networktocode/ntc-ansible).

Answer (score 1):

I think this command will help you to resolve this issue

```
$ export ANSIBLE_LIBRARY=/
```

Ansible will search for modules at the path specified.

Comment: Please explain your answer so future users can understand better and benefit from your answer

Answer (score 0):

`unset ANSIBLE_LIBRARY`

`ANSIBLE_LIBRARY` was set to a bad path which was causing this error.